# Hibernate conditional query

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Hello stackoverflow community.

I ran into difficulties while trying to form a conditional query for Hibernate. I have a search form on the ui that takes different parameters, such as a customer name, surname and his/her financial info - account number, valid from date, etc.

Mainly there are 2 tables: one containing personal information and the other containg financial information of a client. The thing is that this query should first check the personal info fields of a customer and then check if the financial information is not null. If it is not null, it should look in the financial table for the customer id based on the fields entered by the customer. If the financial data fields are empty, it should take any id present in the personal information table, since we want to check all customers for matching the inputted personal info fields(name, surname, mobile).

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT c.ID FROM Customer c WHERE 
(:firstName IS NULL OR LOWER(c.FIRSTNAME) LIKE :firstName)
AND (:lastName IS NULL OR LOWER(c.LASTNAME) LIKE :lastName)
AND (:mobileNum IS NULL OR LOWER(c.MOBILENUM)LIKE :mobileNum) AND c.ID IN
(SELECT a.FK_CUSTOMER_ID CASE WHEN (a.ACCOUNTNUMBER NOT NULL OR VALIDFROM NOT NULL OR VALIDTO NOT NULL)
THEN a.FK_CUSTOMER_ID IN (SELECT a.FK_CUSTOMER_ID FROM ACCOUNT a WHERE
(:accountNumber IS NULL OR a.ACCOUNTNUMBER LIKE :accountNumber)
AND (:validFrom IS NULL OR a.VALIDFROM LIKE :validFrom)
AND (:validTo IS NULL OR a.VALIDTO LIKE :validTo)) END FROM ACCOUNT a));
```

I think there is some syntactical error, but I can't figure out which one.

**Update:**  
Actually @ OldProgrammer was right I posted by mistake the query from sql developer when I was trying to understand what went wrong. Actually I modified my query in the java code itself in order to avoid errors while dealing with Dates.
So my modified code looks like this:

```
    public List<Customer> findBySearchCriteria(SearchCriteria 
    searchCriteria) {
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Customer 
    c LEFT JOIN c.accountList ac WHERE (:firstName IS NULL OR 
    LOWER(c.firstName) LIKE :firstName) AND (:lastName IS NULL OR 
    LOWER(c.lastName) LIKE :lastName) AND (:mobileNum IS NULL OR 
    LOWER(c.mobileNum) LIKE :mobileNum) AND (:accountNumber IS NULL OR 
    LOWER(ac.accountNumber) LIKE :accountNumber)");

    if (searchCriteria.getAccountValidFrom() != null) {
        temp.append("AND (ac.validFrom between :validFrom AND :validFromEndPoint)");
    }
    if (searchCriteria.getAccountValidTo() != null) {
        temp.append("AND (ac.validTo between :validTo AND :validToEndPoint)");
    }

    Query namedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(temp.toString(), Customer.class)
            .setParameter("firstName", searchCriteria.getFirstNameCriteria() == null ?
                    null : "%" + searchCriteria.getFirstNameCriteria().trim().toLowerCase() + "%")
            .setParameter("lastName", searchCriteria.getLastNameCriteria() == null ?
                    null : "%" + searchCriteria.getLastNameCriteria().trim().toLowerCase() + "%")
            .setParameter("mobileNum", searchCriteria.getMobileNumCriteria() == null ?
                    null : "%" + searchCriteria.getMobileNumCriteria().trim().toLowerCase() + "%")
            .setParameter("accountNumber", searchCriteria.getAccountNumCriteria() == null ?
                    null : "%" + searchCriteria.getAccountNumCriteria().toString() + "%");

    if (searchCriteria.getAccountValidFrom() != null) {
        namedQuery.setParameter("validFrom", searchCriteria.getAccountValidFrom())
                .setParameter("validFromEndPoint", searchCriteria.getAccountValidFromEndPoint());
    }

    if (searchCriteria.getAccountValidTo() != null) {
        namedQuery.setParameter("validTo", searchCriteria.getAccountValidTo())
                .setParameter("validToEndPoint", searchCriteria.getAccountValidToEndPoint());
    }

    return namedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

It doesn't really look nice since I have to check twice in order to build query: first time appending query dynamically and the second time setting parameters.

An advice of how to improve this kind of functionality would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with hibernate?

Comment: Is it because you are using multiple labels more than once? In PHP\PDO this can only be achieved by setting emulating prepares to true because the driver does not allow it.

Comment: You've got a comma missing between `(select a.fk_customer_id` and `case when (a.accountnumber ...`, fwiw.